# multiple radio buttons but only one won't fire onCheckedChange asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a set of 3 radio buttons, but the first button doesn't fire the `onCheckedChange` event when you click on it. I put a breakpoint in my c# code at the `SSTypeChanged` function so I know it's not being called when you click on the `Pullback` button.  Can anyone tell me what I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbn_SSPullback" runat="server" 
                 Text="Pullback" CssClass="msRadioButton" 
                 Font-Size="12" GroupName="MSType" 
                 OnCheckedChange="SSTypeChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
<br />
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbn_SSDeadlength" runat="server" 
                 Text="Deadlength" CssClass="msRadioButton" 
                 Font-Size="12" GroupName="MSType"
                 OnCheckedChanged="SSTypeChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
<br />
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbn_SSModular" runat="server" 
                 Text="Modular (Bar Feed Only)" CssClass="msRadioButton" 
                 Font-Size="12" GroupName="MSType" 
                 OnCheckedChanged="SSTypeChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OnCheckedChange="SS` should be  `OnCheckedChanged="SS`

You have a syntax error on the first one.

Comment: ugh Thank you! I didn't realize Visual Studio would make it red if it was wrong and didn't read it closely enough.